# Как сделать приведение типов в артибутах из Object

Tags: java, json

У меня есть класс, который хранит полученное сообщение. Сначала он его сохраняет, достаёт намеренья, а потом по классу этого намеренья парсит в объект уже сами данные сообщения:

Получение данных:

```java
@Override
public void onMessage (WebSocket webSocket, String message) {
    System.out.println(message); // DEBUG
    clients.sendAll(message); // DEBUG

    Helper.MessagePacket packet = Helper.parsePacket(message);
    Commands cmd = Commands.byIntents(packet.intention);
    try {
        packet.parseData(cmd.pattern);
    } catch (NullPointerException _) {
        webSocket.send(JsonStream.serialize(SystemResponses.Errors.MESSAGE_DAMAGED));
        return;
    }

    switch (cmd) {
        case ADMIN_CHANNELS_CREATE, ADMIN_CHANNELS_USERS_JOIN -> {

        }
        case USER_CHANNELS_MESSAGES_POST_NEW -> {
            if (!clientIDVerifier(webSocket, packet.postData.author)) { // Ошибка - атрибута author несуществует
                webSocket.send(JsonStream.serialize(SystemResponses.Errors.PERMISSION_DENIED));
            }
        }
        default -> webSocket.send(JsonStream.serialize(SystemResponses.Errors.MESSAGE_DAMAGED));
    }
}
```

Парсинг:

```
public class Helper {
    public static class MessagePacket {
        final String hash;
        final String[] intention;
        final String preData;
        Object postData;

        public MessagePacket (String[] intention, String controlSum, String data) {
            this.intention = intention;
            this.hash = controlSum;
            this.preData = data;
        }

        public void parseData (Class pattern) {
            postData = JsonIterator.deserialize(preData, pattern);
        }
    }

        @Contract("_ -> new")
    public static @NotNull MessagePacket parsePacket (@NotNull String packet) {
        String[] splitPacket = packet.split("%");

        return new MessagePacket(splitPacket[0].split("-"), splitPacket[1], splitPacket[2]);
    }
```

Определение намерений:

```java
public enum Commands {
    ADMIN_CHANNELS_CREATE(new String[]{"ADMIN", "CHANNELS", "CREATE"}, DataCommands.ChannelCreate.class),
    ADMIN_CHANNELS_USERS_JOIN(new String[]{"ADMIN", "CHANNELS", "USERS", "JOIN"}, DataCommands.ChannelUsersJoin.class),
    ADMIN_CHANNELS_USERS_APPEND(new String[0], null), // TODO
    USER_CHANNELS_MESSAGES_POST_NEW(new String[]{"USER", "CHANNELS", "MESSAGES", "POST", "NEW"}, DataCommands.ChannelMessagesPostNew.class);

    private final String[] intents;
    final Class pattern;

    private Commands(String[] intents, Class pattern) {
        this.intents = intents;
        this.pattern = pattern;
    }

    public static Commands byIntents(String[] intents) {
        return Arrays.stream(Commands.values())
            .filter(v -> Arrays.equals(v.intents, intents))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
    }
}
```

Так непосредственно сами классы команд:

```java
public class DataCommands {
    static class ChannelCreate {
        long owner;
        String title;
    }
    static class ChannelUsersJoin {
        long user;
        long channel;
        String invitation;
    }
    static class ChannelMessagesPostNew {
        long author;
        long channel;
        String text;
    }
}
```

Я нашёл [похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16884097/how-to-change-data-types-without-change-variable-name-java). Но там идёт явное обозначение через `new`. Я попытался сделать аналогичную вещь.

Интерфейс:

```java
public interface MessagePostData {

}
```

Паттерны:

```
public class DataCommands {
    static class ChannelCreate implements MessagePostData {
        long owner;
        String title;
    }
    static class ChannelUsersJoin implements MessagePostData {
        long user;
        long channel;
        String invitation;
    }
    static class ChannelMessagesPostNew implements MessagePostData {
        long author;
        long channel;
        String text;
    }
}
```

Парсинг:

```
public void parseData (Class pattern) {
    postData = (MessagePostData) JsonIterator.deserialize(preData, pattern);
}
```

Но атрибут всё равно не находится. Можно ли как-нибудь перетипизировать атрибут на мой класс-паттер данных сообщения, не доставая его из объекта?